# Syncfusion Dashboard: load data from Data Source dynamically by swap parameters

Tags: user-interface, dashboard, syncfusion

I try to use **Syncfusion Dashboard Designer** for data visualization.

I use **Web Data Source** as connection type.

I want to filter data by some parameters, for example date range filter (**DatePicker**).

The problem is that Dashboard (I try dashboard preview) loads data from Data Source once and then filtering all at the UI level.. i.e. caches data.
Also when I try update manually from UI in browser requests don't go to the server :

[image]

It updates **only** when I use **refresh button** in Dashboard designer Data Source editor:

[image]

Also `Refresh Settings` -> `Enable Auto Refresh` not works in **dashboard preview**:

[image]

This is a problem because I have a lot of data for several years that constantly adding and I don't want to pull everything at once.

Is it possible to **load data from Data Source dynamically** by swap startDate and endDate parameters from DatePicker?

Example:

```
http://host_name/webservice/some_rest_method?startTime={swapped_startTime}&endTime={swapped_endTime}&group=false
```

So web data source  will return the data that is required by request.

I'm sure that this should be because this is one of the main things and this is good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the Dashboard SDK platform as an alternate solution. A sample application has been created in ASP.Net MVC to demonstrate your requirement. Please find the sample from the following link http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/LocalEmbeddedDashboard-304170304 .

Copy the Dashboard Service hosted URL and paste it in the file "Controllers\DashboardViewerController.cs" as shown below and run the application. 
[DashboardViewerController.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlzqj.png)

In the sample application we have a date picker widget where you can choose the start and end range of the data. Upon selecting the range the query will be generated with the selected value and the dashboard will be showcasing the filtered data.

Please refer the code in the files “Controllers\DashboardViewerController.cs” and “Views/DashboardViewer/Index.cshtml”.

Comment: You can download and extract the sample from the link. Run the sample in Visual studio. To run the sample Dashboard SDK platform is required. You can download the SDK Platform build from the link https://www.syncfusion.com/products/dashboard After installing the Build follow the steps in the documentation to host the dashboard service in IIS express https://help.syncfusion.com/dashboard-platform/dashboard-sdk/installation-and-deployment#hosting-dashboard-service-in-iis-express

Comment: You can find our documentation on change connection string in the link https://help.syncfusion.com/dashboard-platform/dashboard-sdk/how-to/change-data-connection-string-in-dashboard

Answer (score 0):

The current version (2.2.0.31) of Syncfusion Dashboard  doesn't support dynamic requests to data sources. 
Also it doesn't support dynamic parameters.